# ORACLE VENDOR CODE 936 Observation

Tags: oracle

In Oracle while doing this

```
Select 0 as "Id", column_1, column_2 from table_name
```

I am having the right answer. I did not have any problem with the execution. But if I do this:

```
Select 0 as "Id",* from table_name
```

I am getting the VENDOR CODE 936 error message.

The question is, is it possible to fix the second expression to make it work.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

```
select 0 as "ID",  t.*
from table_name t
```

you need to alias the table in order to make this work